# Can I use Ubuntu on my Dell Venue 8 pro?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, dell

I am using a Dell Venue 8 pro. I think Windows 8.1 is not a good OS for tablet devices. I believe that Ubuntu is working well on tablets, but I've read that people are having issues with touch input and internet access when running Ubuntu on this device.

Is it possible to use Ubuntu on Dell Venue 8 pro?

If it is possible, how can I boot it?

Comment: You should have a look at https://www.happyassassin.net/fedlet-a-fedora-remix-for-bay-trail-tablets/
It's Fedora,but still not good to use. You should know that at this time sdio devices doesn't show up (in fact it's changing) and there's still no WiFi support for this card. Now only one thing to do : wait and hope everything will go fast.

Comment: If that tablet has usb port, use wireless keyboard with usb receiver. There's also mini-usb to usb converters, if that's what the tablet needs. If there's a bluetooth on that tablet, bluetooth keyboard might be even better option.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this a hardware recommendation question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

It's almost fully working with Ubuntu 14.10; the touch screen is working, but still no Wifi or Bluetooth.

32-bit UEFI gives a bit of trouble after installing. See [32-bit UEFI boot on Asus T100](http://www.jfwhome.com/2014/03/07/perfect-ubuntu-or-other-linux-on-the-asus-transformer-book-t100/)

[Here is a thread on this topic in Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2187204&page=10)